# qemu possibillity to change monitor input between vm and host

Tags: qemu, kvm

Not sure if this is the right place to ask this question but here goes. I have managed to setup a Windows 10 VM with qemu and GPU passthrough following this guide [here](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/PCI_passthrough_via_OVMF). According to those instructions, it is possible to use the same keyboard and mouse between host and VM by pressing both Ctrl keys. This works flawlessly.

I have now discovered that my monitor (I have only one) can be controlled from the command line to switch inputs using `ddcutil`.

I was wondering if there is a way such that when I press both Ctrl keys to switch controls between host and VM (and vice versa) the input is also switched?

For example:

1. start VM, press Both Ctrl keys and controls are switched to VM and the Monitor is set to the input that I assigned to the VM.
2. while in the VM, press the two Ctrl keys again and the controls are switched back to the host together with the monitor input assigned to the host.

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

I am the developer of [ddcutil](https://www.ddcutil.com). I can't directly answer your question, but I may be able to give you some useful information.

In your qemu/passthrough configuration, it should be possible to issue DDC commands from the Windows VM using a Windows program, e.g.softMCCS. Virtual Control Panel feature x60 (Input Source) should enable you to switch from Windows to the Linux host.

What I think you want to do is issue a command in Linux to switch the input from the Windows VM to the Linux host.  Unfortunately, this may or may not be possible depending on how the monitor implements feature x60.  Some monitors accept DDC commands from any connector no matter what the current input source.  Others accept commands only from the current input source.  The only way to find out is by testing.

All this presumes, of course, that the monitor implements feature x60.  Most do, but some do not.